# Re-using custom laravel commands

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have created my own commands using `php artisan make:command CommandName` this suits my needs so I want to include it in other projects. Is there some way to do this using `composer` commands?

Comment: Create a package and distribute it through composer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @u_mulder has mentioned - you'd have to create and publish a package, which you can then require via composer. Once you've done that - you'd have to then register the command from within the `app/Console/Kernel.php` as per these instructions https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan#registering-commands